# Get to Tibidabo with Hola Barcelona card. Is it possible?

Tags: tickets, public-transport, spain, transportation, barcelona

I'm traveling to Barcelona next week and I will use [Hola Barcelona](https://www.holabarcelona.com/tickets/hola-bcn-barcelona-travel-card) card for public transport.

Searching on [Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Sagrada+Familia,+La+Sagrada+Familia,+Carrer+de+Mallorca,+Barcelona,+Spain/Tibidabo,+08035+Barcelona,+Spain/@41.4057186,2.1256742,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x12a4a2dcd83dfb93:0x9bd8aac21bc3c950!2m2!1d2.1743558!2d41.4036299!1m5!1m1!1s0x12a49789cff3db45:0xdb92ebc64b4e2a63!2m2!1d2.118611!2d41.4225!3e3) for a journey, let's say from Sagrada Familia it shows that one have to take the metro line, funicular (Vallvidrera) and another bus to get there.

My question is: are all of those means included with Hola Barcelona card?

Answer (score 5):

If you take the route Google suggested at the moment (involving only funicular from Vallvidrera Inferior to Superior, then taking 111), you can use the Hola Barcelona Card.

The Hola Barcelona card includes public transport within Zone 1 (https://doc.atm.cat/ca/xarxa_ferrov_global.pdf), in which Tibidabo stop is situated.

Note though the Vallvidrera Funicular is included in the network, **but the Tibidabo Funicular is not.**

Comment: +1 But in case you are going to Tibidabo for the amusement park there, please notice that the Tibidabo Funicular is included in the amusement park ticket. Therefore, it might not be very important to you whether it is included in Hola Barcelona Card.